# change color of div and its siblings on hover w/o javascript

Tags: html, css

I have two divs floated next to one another:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child_1" style="float:left"> content </div>
    <div id="child_2" style="float:left"> content </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

When either div is hovered over, I'd like to change the colors of both divs (to something different). Say, one yellow, the other red. Is there a way to do this? I put the div `id="parent"` in there thinking that I could do something when that is hovered over; change the divs with this id (or class) to this color within the parent. But I don't really know if this is possible. Also, jquery hover events always seem very delayed with respect to css, so I am trying to avoid using a script. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#parent:hover div#child_1 {
  color: red;
}

div#parent:hover div#child_2 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks! is it necessary to have that first `div` before `#parent`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to child_1 and child_2, call it "children" or whatever you want.  Then use this CSS:

```
.children:hover #child_1 { color: red; }
.children:hover #child_2 { color: yellow; }
```